# json deserialize array without a property name

Tags: c#, json

I have a json like this

```
{"1":"#ff0051","2":"#d000ff","3":"#2200ff","4":"#00ff59"}
```

How can I read these values since they don't have a property name? It is a bit difficult to think of a way.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON.Net

```
var s = "{\"1\":\"#ff0051\",\"2\":\"#d000ff\",\"3\":\"#2200ff\",\"4\":\"#00ff59\"}";
var o = JObject.Parse(s);
```

Then you can read the property value

```
Console.WriteLine(o["1"]);
```

Please note that you also need to install [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) Nuget Package.

Comment: Thank you. this is exactly what i was looking for.